# php combine and sort array by quantity rule (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm stuck) 
There is two arrays, `$a` and `$b`. I want take and "sort" values from `$b` to receive `$final` array like that:

```
array:6 [
  0 => [1 => 1]
  1 => [1 => 3]
  2 => [1 => 5]
  3 => [2 => 7]
  4 => [3 => 9]
  5 => [3 => 11]
]
```

but I get this wrong array:

```
array:6 [
  0 => [1 => 1]
  1 => [1 => 3]
  2 => [1 => 5]
  3 => [2 => 1]
  4 => [3 => 1]
  5 => [3 => 3]
]
```

Code:

```
$final = [];
$c = 0;
$a = [3,1,2];
$b = [1,3,5,7,9,11];

foreach($a as $k => $v){
    $c++;
    foreach($b as $key => $val){
        if($v > $key)
            $final[] = [$c => $val];
    }
}
dump($final);
```

How can tell to if statement inside of foreach($b) to **also** verify that $key should be bigger than its previous value? Because I see that wrong array at 3rd index takes first element from `$b` `( .. 3 => [2 => 1] .. )`

Tried different approaches, but not successful.

Comment: Can you please explain better what you're trying to do, are you trying to combine both arrays and then sort it?

Comment: @latr.88 $a is the rule. 3+1+2 == quantity of elements in $b. I need to combine(get) first 3 elements and save to which rule they related. So the correct array contains [number of the rule=>value of $b]

Comment: @latr.88 ..then I take one element from second rule, so in $final array should go 4th array (.. 3=>[2=>7] ..), but as you can see instead of 4th element from $b (which ==7) there goes first element from $b (which==1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify array a, an easier to do so:

```
$i=0; // Index of array a
foreach($b as $v){
    // while a[$i] is not zero
    if(! $a[$i]) {
       // Go next item of array a
       $i++;
    } 
    // Put to final array  
    $final[] = [$i+1 => $v];
    // Decrease counter
    $a[$i]--;

}
print_r($final);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1055647)

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you! Additional thanks to "demo", cuz I thought your answer must be inside foreach($a) :)